# Numpy modulo-like function but I want to get difference to closest multiple of some number

Tags: python, numpy

I thought this is going to be an easy problem, but I have not found a satisfactory solution to this. I know this could be done with some loop and comparing values, but is there a compact version to the following problem?

I want to get the distance of some numpy array, e.g. `v = np.array([0.5, 2.1, 1.9, 4.2])` to the number 2 and multiples of it. So something like modulo, but 1.9%2 should be 0.1 and not 1.9.

So the expected result of the function for the given vector is `mod_like_function(v, 2)= [0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2]`. And I would prefer no loops and if statements, because I would like this to be jittable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the folloing strategy:

1. round to the nearest multiple of the denominator
2. compute absolute differences to rounded values

In code that would be:

```py
def mod_like_function(x, q):
    rounded_x = q * np.round(x/q)
    return np.abs(x-rounded_x)
```

I dont know what you mean by jittable in the context of python and numpy, but this solution does not contain loops at the python-level, so it vectorizes over `x`.